# Exporting all file locations that could not be found on iTunes

Tags: itunes, windows, music, script

I'm running Windows 7 64 bit and am using iTunes. I previously had an issue where when iTunes organized my media library (after transferring all my music over), the file names were auto-truncated to 40 characters. This effectively broke a large portion of my library.

To see all the songs that were broken I created a smart playlist of "dead" songs and exported that playlist information. Unfortunately, the dead locations did not get exported when I chose `File -> Export Playlist`, only the other metadata was exported. This is strange because when I actually select `Get Info` on the song, I can see the file path it is looking for.

Is there some way to get this information exported? I'm trying to write a script to auto-rename the files it finds to the correct (longer) file names.

Edit:

Here is an example:

Let's say I have a song that is broken in iTunes (the file path is incorrect). In iTunes this appears with the correct metadata. I can check the metadata by right clicking on the song in question and selecting `Get Info`.

My song structure looks like this:

```
Artist: DJ Rashad
Song: Last Winter
Album: Double Cup
Genre: Footwork
Location: C:\My Music\iTunes\DJ Rashad\Double Cup\DJ Rashad - Last Winter.mp3
```

In this case the `Location` attribute is incorrect, which is fine. But I still need this data when I export the information about the track. So I drag this track into its own playlist and export the information via `File -> Export Playlist`. I expect to see the structure above but instead what appears in the corresponding file is the following:

```
Artist: DJ Rashad
Song: Last Winter
Album: Double Cup
Genre: Footwork
Location:
```

Since iTunes does not find the location, it exports an empty location. Since I am writing a script to correct some broken paths, I do not want an empty location. I want the last known location of the file (the one that is displayed when viewing `Get Info`). How can I export the complete information under the `Location` attribute?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having trouble understanding what exactly you want to export.  Could you provide a couple examples?  Thanks

Comment: @Cullub I've edited my original question to include an example :)

Comment: Where did it truncate? Your example file has less than 40 chars in the name

Comment: @Tetsujin I apologize, I created an example with less than 40 characters. Regardless, I just want to find out how to export where iTunes last saw the file (if the file itself was broken).

Comment: I don't have an actual working method as yet but was having a look through the library.xml & wondered if the truncation was with or without the extension - for example `C:\My Music\iTunes\DJ Rashad\Double Cup\DJ Rashad - Last Wi` or `C:\My Music\iTunes\DJ Rashad\Double Cup\DJ Rashad - Las.mp3` or even the awful old Windows `NAME~1.mp3`style.

Comment: @Tetsujin The file currently gets truncated and then the `.mp3` extension is added. So it might look like `DJ Rashad - Las.mp3`

Answer (score 1):

suggest you go a different path.

first remove all the broken links in itunes
[Can I easily view all songs that iTunes can't locate in Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47990/can-i-easily-view-all-songs-that-itunes-cant-locate-in-finder)

then drag&drop your complete lib back in itunes (there wont be duplicates, if you drag files that are already linked/imported.)

done

Comment: One problem with this method is that all my metadata (ratings most importantly) is lost.